# Optimize query mysql search

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following SQL but its execution this very slow, takes about 45 seconds, the table has 15 million record, how can I improve?

```
SELECT A.*, B.ESPECIE
FROM 
(
SELECT 
    A.CODIGO_DOCUMENTO,
    A.DOC_SERIE,A.DATA_EMISSAO,
    A.DOC_NUMERO,
    A.CF_NOME,
    A.CF_SRF,
    A.TOTAL_DOCUMENTO, 
    A.DOC_MODELO
FROM MOVIMENTO A  

WHERE
    A.CODIGO_EMPRESA = 1
        AND A.CODIGO_FILIAL = 5
        AND A.DOC_TIPO_MOVIMENTO = 1
        AND A.DOC_MODELO IN ('65','55')
        AND (A.CF_NOME LIKE '%TEXT_SEARCH%'
        OR A.CF_CODIGO LIKE 'TEXT_SEARCH%'
        OR A.CF_SRF LIKE 'TEXT_SEARCH%'
        OR A.DOC_SERIE LIKE 'TEXT_SEARCH%'
        OR A.DOC_NUMERO LIKE 'TEXT_SEARCH%')
ORDER BY A.DATA_EMISSAO DESC , A.CODIGO_DOCUMENTO DESC
LIMIT 0, 100
) A 
LEFT JOIN MODELODOCUMENTOFISCAL B ON A.DOC_MODELO = B.CODMODELO
```

Comment: Put an EXPLAIN before this query,edit your question with the results

Comment: How many rows is it if you run the query without the text search conditions?

Comment: # id, select_type, table, type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows, Extra
'1', 'PRIMARY', '<derived2>', 'ALL', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '100', NULL
'1', 'PRIMARY', 'B', 'ALL', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '34', 'Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)'
'2', 'DERIVED', 'A', 'index', 'PRIMARY,DOC_TIPO_MOVIMENTO,FK_MOVIMENTO_CODPAGTO,IDX_DOC_MODELO,IDX_CONSULTA,IDX_CF_CODIGO_CF_TIPO,CF_CODIGO,IDX_ITEM_REF,IDX_PDV', 'DATA_EMISSAO', '6', NULL, '14350757', 'Using where'

Answer (score 0):

For this query, I would start with an index on `MOVIMENTO(CODIGO_EMPRESA, CODIGO_FILIAL, DOC_MODELO)` and `MODELODOCUMENTOFISCAL(CODMODELO)`.

That should speed the query.

If it doesn't you may need to consider a full text search to handle the `LIKE` clauses.  I do note that you only have a wildcard at the beginning of one of the patterns.  Is that intentional?